# Elegant way to skin form elements with images?

Tags: html, css, forms, themes

I've spent the better part of the day searching for a top-notch solution for skinning form elements with sprite images and have come up with very little. There are several offering based around JS-CSS styles, but none that use images for each element.

I am particularly interested in skinning text fields, text areas, submit buttons, and perhaps select menus - other elements are simple enough to skin with plain CSS.

Is there a capable, flexible, and compatible way to do this?

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking for here. Is it some kind of desktop editor a la Eclipse or Dreamweaver that makes calculating Sprite coordinates easier? There's http://www.spritecow.com for instance. But what you want exactly, I can't tell.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements

Comment: Yes, something in the direction of Mijan's link is what I'm after. My problem is that most jQuery solutions don't quite match up to what I need, which is the ability to style all form elements with image sprites. Many stop at just CSS3 styling, which isn't good enough in my case because I need to support IE8.